# Cutting and welding a BBQ lid to make it narrower

Tags: welding

I have a  fairly heavy-gauge park style BBQ made by Pilot Rock.

If you needed to reduce the width of  this BBQ lid by a couple inches (*facing the grill*), how and where would you make the cuts and then weld the pieces back together?

[image: BBQ lid]

Comment: Have you attempted to contact Pilot Rock to see if they have a suitably-sized replacement lid?  The cost of a new right-sized part is worth checking out, if it exists.

Comment: Also, how are you dealing with the hinges?  Based on the thumbnail, at least one will have to move over on the lower part too.

Comment: @Criggie:  this was the smallest lid they had available.

Answer (score 3):

I would try to cut as close to one end as i could so you effectively have just the  curved end.

Then cut out the "couple of inches"  off the end that you removed the end piece from and weld your  curved end plate back on.

This would be the most aesthetically pleasing but you could remove a section of the middle, you would have a weld bead in the middle of course.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: A single weld in the middle would be symmetrical, but blatantly obvious... Depends how good a welder OP is (or knows)  Plus getting it aligned straight might be a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alaska Man, but I would also considering cutting off both ends. The reasons being:

1. The shape may not be a true cylinder, so cutting material out of just one end may make it appear lopsided.
2. If you cut one end and re-weld, you've got to make your weld perfect and profile it in order to match the other end. If you cut both ends and re-weld, you can make the weld be part of the look. It will be symmetrical and if done well, it can look like the factory build it that way.

Good luck!